# Dialogflow - creating an Intent with an input context, via v2 API

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I'm working on a script to programmatically create a bunch of intents. I want to set the input context for these intents to a specific value. I have working code that creates the full intent - but I can't get the parameter for input context to work.

This works (in python), but does not create an input context:

```
intents_client = dialogflow_v2beta1.IntentsClient.from_service_account_json(PROJECT_JSON)
parent = intents_client.project_agent_path(PROJECT_ID)
training_phrases = []
part1 = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part(text="hello ")
parts = []
parts.append(part1)
training_phrase = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.TrainingPhrase(parts=parts)
training_phrases.append(training_phrase)
text = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.Message.Text(text=["say hello"])
message = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.Message(text=text)
messages = []
messages.append(message)

intent = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent(
  display_name='Mike_Hello',
  training_phrases=training_phrases,
  messages=messages)
response = intents_client.create_intent(parent, intent, language_code=LANGUAGE)
```

But, when I add the following to my Intent definition:

```
intent = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent(
    display_name='Mike_Hello',
    input_context_names=['5000'],
    training_phrases=training_phrases,
    messages=messages)
```

(ie - adding the `input_context_names` parameter)

The intent creation fails with an error:

> Resource name does not match format 'projects/{project_id}/agent/sessions/{session_id}/contexts/{context_id}'

I tried creating a context with a context client and `create_context`, but it fails with the same error. The `create_context` API seems to me to be more related to creating a context for inputting into `detect_intent`, as it wants a live SESSION_ID as input.

I can replace `["5000"]` in the input_context above with `'projects/PROJECT_ID/agent/sessions/-/contexts/5000'`, and I get the same error.

Bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Using `['projects/PID/agent/sessions/-/contexts/CID']` looks like it should be correct. Two questions: (1) Are you sure it is in a list (the way you write it isn't quite clear what your code actually looks like). (2) Is "5000" the actual name? Have you tried something with a leading letter or no numbers at all? (The docs say that "5000" should be a valid CID, but worth a try.)

Comment: I have tried alpha context ID's, same thing. I've tried creating a list variable with the one entry, and multiple entries, and the same failure happens. Full exception is: google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: Resource name does not match format 'projects/{project_id}/agent/sessions/{session_id}/contexts/{context_id}' or 'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location_id}/agent/sessions/{session_id}/contexts/{context_id}'.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

The entity string:
`'projects/' + PROJECT_ID + '/agent/sessions/-/contexts/my_ctx_name'`

works great.

The entity string:
`'/projects/' + PROJECT_ID + '/agent/sessions/-/contexts/my_ctx_name'`

does not work. My problem was the leading '/' before 'projects'.